# Should we ever call setClientId() on the connection factory?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-jms

This is in the context of creating a durable subscription. 
There is a setClientId() in [DefaultMessageListenerContainer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractJmsListeningContainer.html#setClientId%28java.lang.String%29)  and another one in [SingleConnectionFactory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/connection/SingleConnectionFactory.html#setClientId%28java.lang.String%29).

My understanding is :

- Durable subscription is for a consumer/subscriber.
- Different consumers should be capable of using different client ids.
- Different consumers should be able to share a connection.
- There is one (ListenerContainer,Listener) pair per consumer.

So, it makes sense to setClientId() at the ListenerContainer.

**But, Why would there be a setClientId() at the connection factory level ?**

Even though the SingleConnectionFactory has only a single connection, that connection could be shared by multiple consumers, across multiple sessions. Right ?
Needless to say that it is more dangerous for a CachingConnectionFactory (which inherits this method from SingleConnectionFactory).

**Extended version:**
Can we say one should NOT use the setClientId() on a Single/CachingConnectionFactory ?
This is made even more imperative by the following statement in DefaultMessageListenerContainer's setClientId():

> Furthermore, a client ID can only be assigned if the original
>   ConnectionFactory hasn't already assigned one

So, if someone accidentally setClientId on the CachingConnectionFactory, future sets of the client id on the DefaultMessageListenerContainer would be no-ops !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But, Why would there be a setClientId() at the connection factory level ?

`setClientId()` on the connection factory is used to administratively set the client id, to prevent consumer applications from setting it manually; in fact, according to JMS spec, if client id is set by the client when it was already set by the factory, an exception is thrown.

> Can we say one should NOT use the setClientId() on a
>   Single/CachingConnectionFactory?

If you need to create durable subscriptions for different subscribers, each with its own client id, use `subscriber.setClientId()`, because if you use `connectionFactory.setClientId()` and attempt to create multiple connections from the same factory with client id already set, the factory will throw an exception complaining that "connection *clientId* is already connected."

Personally, I like having flexibility and complete control in my code, so I use `subscriber.setClientId()`